# Linked list creating a new node for an item that already exists in list

Tags: python

I am adding nodes to the end of my linked list that is counting the frequencies of characters from a given file. However, my code doesn't seem to be iterating fully through the linked list as it creates a new node for a node that already exists in the list.

```py
def add(self, new_item):
    if self.head == None:
        self.head  = FreqNode(new_item)
        return

    current = self.head

    while (current.next_node):
        if current.data == new_item:
            current.frequency += 1
            return
        current = current.next_node

    current.next_node = FreqNode(new_item)
```

A section of the output is shown below

```py
  20:  's' = 13341
  21:  's' = 1
  22:  'y' = 3461
  23:  'm' = 5441
  24:  'i' = 15916
  25:  'i' = 1
  26:  ',' = 3178
  27:  'w' = 3824
  28:  'd' = 6114
  29:  'v' = 1897
  30:  '.' = 1850
  31:  '.' = 1
  32:  '#' = 1
  33:  '*' = 27
  34:  '*' = 1
  35:  ''' = 112
  36:  'z' = 24
  37:  'x' = 386
  38:  'x' = 1
  39:  'q' = 193
  40:  'q' = 1
  41:  '?' = 88
  42:  '?' = 1
```

Why is the add function not counting the frequency of a node already in the list but creating a new node instead?

Comment: If you are counting the frequency of characters in a file, you should be using a dict.  A linked list is does not give instant access to a character like a dict does.  Is there an educational reason why you are trying to leverage a LL?

Comment: The problem I am working on requires a linked list, that is why I'm doing it. The main focus of my issue is why my while loop does not iterate through the last node therefore not adding to its frequency.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated in the comments, you're approaching your problem in a very C-like fashion, while you should be using the standard library.

But regardless of that, the problem with your code is that when you are adding an item `x`, and an entry for `x` is at the end of your list, `current.next_node` is `None`, your `while` loop is skipped, and you are adding a new node for the same item. After that, the counts are added to the first node, leaving you with a pair `(x, ...), (x, 1)`. To avoid that you can do e.g.

```
while True:
    if current.data == new_item:
        current.frequency += 1
        return
    if current.next_node is None:
        break
    current = current.next_node

current.next_node = FreqNode(new_item)
```